# How was the First Order tracking the Resistance in the Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In TLJ, a big deal is made about how the First Order is able to track the Resistance (lead) ship

> through hyperspace.

Everyone seems surprised that this is possible.

> Rose and Finn comment that the tracking mechanism must be similar to other, pre-existing tracking mechanisms, which is why they know what to destroy, but they don't seem to know where this new ability comes from.

Is it ever made clear how the First Order is doing this? Or is it just "new technology"?

Comment: I think because the "How" doesn't really matter. The films don't focus much on the "How" of the technolog, although I wouldn't be surprised if something is developed for some companion wor (Visual Dictionary)

Comment: Shucks I really wanted to ask this...

Comment: They put the Trace on them. :p

Comment: They had an explanation but it was too technical/complicated to understand without a second viewing.

Comment: My guess: it's based on Starkiller Base technology. That was a weapon that shoots through hyperspace, they must've developed some way of looking through hyperspace in order to aim it. But really, hyperspace is fictional, I'm guessing "it just works" is probably the best explanation we're going to get.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - You understimate my powers, youngling

Comment: Don't forget that every should not be so surprised.  Vader tracked the Tantive IV when it jumped into hyperspace at the end of Rogue One.

Comment: @JK - That was a different method. The Tantive IV was leaking all kinds of fluids

Comment: I think this is beyond accepted technology based on time given to Hux and Snope discussing an “arrangement” to track the Rebel fleet.

Comment: Didn't Leia had a tracking device that kind of worked across hyperspace ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is addressed in the film's [Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) tie-in factbook. In short, it's a combination of unheard-of levels of computer processing power (using hyperspace as a way of compressing processing time) as well as advanced hyperspace sensors and records of millions of previous hyperspace transits.

**It's still a guess, but a guess based on trillions of probability calculations.**

> *The First Order tracks targets through hyperspace using a combination
>   of technological advances and brute-force data crunching. The
>   shipboard tracking control complex boasts the data-sifting power of a
>   planetary intel hub, linking huge computer arrays to databanks loaded
>   with centuries of combat reports and astrogation data.*
>
> *A static hyperspace field generated around the machines then
>   accelerates their processing power to unheard-of levels. A targets
>   last known trajectory yields trillions of potential destinations, but
>   the system can assess them with terrifying speed.*

---

For a bit of fun, it's worth pointing out that we see the system in its infancy in Rogue One, one of the research projects with data on file at the Scarif base.

[image]

Comment: Ooh, nice easter egg find

Comment: As above, why do Hux an Snope discuss it if the tech is accepted?

Comment: Sounds like the First Order has a working quantum computer.

Comment: @Scott - Technically, if you could slow time down over a specific area, a ZX81 could out-perform a super-computer

Answer (score 2):

It's new technology. There's a scene (no screenplays to quote so running off memory here) where they're plotting the whole shut-it-down bit and Poe notes it's new stuff. Given the fact that

> The First Order and the Rebellion are buying military stuff from the same people

it's entirely possible this came through back-channels or intelligence

Comment: I'm sure OP was aware that it's new technology, the question is how did they do it?