# How was the Resistance exposed?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, the-resistance

At the start of *The Last Jedi* the Resistance is in full retreat. From the opening crawl:

> The FIRST ORDER reigns. Having decimated the peaceful Republic, Supreme Leader Snoke now deploys his merciless legions to seize military control of the galaxy.
>
> Only General Leia Organa’s band of RESISTANCE fighters stand against the rising tyranny, certain that Jedi Master Luke Skywalker will return and restore a spark of hope to the fight.
>
> **But the Resistance has been exposed.** As the First Order speeds toward the rebel base, the brave heroes mount a desperate escape...."

How was the Resistance exposed exactly? What caused them to evacuate?

Comment: Ah. That explains it. Those Dreadnought and the rest of the fleet were there merely to arrest the Resistance for indecent exposure :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They were exposed because they sent out a recon flight to find Starkiller base...

> “The scan data from Captain Snap Wexley’s reconnaissance flight confirms everything Finn has told us,” Poe announced to the group.
>   *The Force Awakens novelization by Alan Dean Foster, Chapter XIV*

... and that flight was tracked back to their home base:

> Hux was clearly gratified to be the bearer of good news. “**We were able to track their reconnaissance ship back to the Ileenium system**. We are coordinating with our own reconnaissance craft in the area in order to lock down the specific location of their base.”
>   Snoke replied with cold satisfaction. “We do not need it. Prepare the weapon. Destroy their system.”
>   *The Force Awakens novelization by Alan Dean Foster, Chapter XV*

and

> The general halted before the dais and bowed. “**We were able to track their reconnaissance ship back to the Ileenium system**. We are coordinating with our own spy vessels to lock down the specific location of their base.”
>   “We do not need it. Prepare the weapon. Destroy their system,” the Supreme Leader said.
>   *The Force Awakens Junior Novelization by Michael Kogge, Ch 16*

Comment: Wait does this mean that had they flown to a different system that the First Order would have just blown away an entirely different system?

Comment: @enderland - presumably, they organized those "spy vessels" anyway.

Answer (score 12):

The First Order found out their location before the destruction of their Starkiller Base in the previous film. Having failed to destroy it with their super-weapon, they resort to more conventional means; sending a big fleet of ships to blow it up from orbit.

> **GENERAL HUX:** *We have their location. **[We tracked their reconnaissance ship to the Ileenium system](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/1408ac5f-e3e5-4b41-9e2a-c18926c50bbe).***
>
> **SNOKE:** *Good. Then we will crush them once and for all. Prepare the weapon.*
>
> <sub><sup>Star Wars: The Force Awakens</sup></sub>

As a nice little easter egg, we finally know *how* the First Order was able to track the Resistance's ship back to its base, presumably by using the [hyperspace tracking technology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176357/how-was-the-first-order-tracking-the-resistance-in-the-last-jedi) that appears in The Last Jedi.

Comment: Is this line in the film? Whereabouts does it come?

Comment: From the film; https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/1408ac5f-e3e5-4b41-9e2a-c18926c50bbe

Comment: Speedy. Thanks.